# How do I make a subscription update when another collection, not returned by the publish function, changes?

Tags: meteor

I've adapted server.js from the Parties example.

Instead of having "directory" publish all the users I want it to publish only those users that:

- own a party the current user is invited to
- are invited to a party the current user is invited to
- are invited to a party the current user owns

See here: https://github.com/dimfisch/meteor-dependency/blob/master/parties/server/server.js

The problem is that when the current user invites a new user (new in the sense that they haven't been party-related previously) or gets invited by a new user, the "directory" subscription doesn't update, since the reactivity is on the cursor returned, which doesn't change in these cases.

Here are the steps to reproduce this situation:

1. open two different clients, say Joe and Kate
2. Joe creates a new private party and invites Kate
3. Kate sees that new party, but doesn't get any info about Joe in Meteor.users
4. I want Joe to show up in Kate's client

So the question is, how can that be achieved?
One potential route is to make the "parties" cursor observeChanges, in the "directory" publish function. But I'm not sure this would actually work and I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward solution.

Comment: Slightly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437102/how-to-resubscribe-to-a-meteor-collection-when-another-related-collection-change

Comment: The repro doesn't work... Joe can't invite Kate because the complete users list isn't published.  Perhaps update with commands to run in console instead?

Comment: @alanning yes, that's true. My app is based on the Parties example and I have added a lot of code for users to be able to invite others to a party with an email address, but that's not in the Parties example... so here's what I did: I created two users, joe@example.com and kate@example.com. password for both of them is "example". I created a party for Joe called "Test Party 1". I invited Kate by typing the following in the console: Meteor.call("invite", Session.get("selected"), "Ld96cayfGZrzSLLn2") the last part is Kate's userId. [message too long, follow-up in next comment]

Comment: It worked, but doing Meteor.users.find().fetch() on Kate's console still showed one object, namely herself. Nothing for Joe. Of course if you refresh the page then it will show up, but that's not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use observeChanges on the client-side.  Whenever the `parties` collection changes, stop and restart the `users` subscription, which forces the publish function to re-run.

The `parties` publish function would only send party information that the current user has access to.  And the `users` publish function would send down the appropriate user info for any users that have access to the same parties.

Server-side, you could probably do the same thing but it would be more work... Publish `parties` as normal but manually publish only the `users` that the share parties with the user.  Not sure how the remove case would work though.  Seems like it would be a pain and potentially not very efficient.

Comment: What would I have to run ObserveChanges on? Meteor.subscribe("directory") doesn't return a Cursor, I think.